# How to detect persistent notification (FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT)?

Tags: android, android-notifications

My app has a special ON and OFF feature. So when the app is in ON mode, the notification is always present via flags

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
```

When the app is in OFF mode, the notification is gone. The ON and OFF modes has **nothing** with app running or not!!!

So, when a user closes app (`onStop` is being called) and reopens the app, I need app to **detect if it is in ON or OFF mode**. That is why I would need an app to detect if this notification exists or not.

How can I detect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store this on/off state somewhere else, such as [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Then post/cancel the notification to match the on/off state.

Comment: I know this :). I was hoping there is a better solution.